# Custom MimeType file won't upload using HttpComponent

Tags: java, http, uploading

Okay, so I am trying to upload an audio file to a server using Java/Apache-HttpComponents. Server expects that file's MimeType be "audio/wav". Here is what i am trying:

```
        File file = new File("testfile2.wav");

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uploadURL);
        HttpResponse httpResponse;
        String htmlResponse = "";

        MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file, ContentType.create("audio/wav"));

        builder.addPart("mediaListForm.mediaForms[0].description", new StringBody("RBT Name", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
        builder.addPart("mediaListForm.mediaForms[0].artistId", new StringBody("2649", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
        builder.addPart("mediaListForm.mediaForms[0].categoryId", new StringBody("2", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
        builder.addPart("mediaListForm.mediaForms[0].file;", fileBody);


        httpPost.setEntity(builder.build());
```

If i do not specify MimeType then default MimeType is sent as "application/octet-stream" and server rejects my request. If I specify mime type as above `new FileBody(file, ContentType.create("audio/wav"));` then Server says `Invalid value for field mediaListForm.mediaForms[0].file`. I tried debugging and explored request object which is like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryqQFxF4y3FTYY3pEf
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mediaListForm.mediaForms[0].file";
Content-Type: audio/wav
```

File name is missing from my request, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about why wouldn't method below work:

```
builder.addPart("mediaListForm.mediaForms[0].file", fileBody);
//If filebody contains custom contentType it does not work otherwise file is uploaded but server rejects it because of invalid contentType
```

Now there are multiple methods for adding file to our entity, some methods expect FileInputStream some expects File, use the one expected by server like I tried FileInputStream it server threw an exception and I figured it out that I had to send File instead, so this method worked like a charm.

```
builder.addBinaryBody("mediaListForm.mediaForms[0].file", file, ContentType.create("audio/wav"), rbt.getFullPath());
```